# Hibernate setMaxResults() with H2 SqlGrammarException

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm attempting to get a certain number of rows from the database given a certain user and a max amount.  Here is what the code looks like currently:

```
@Override
public Collection<TestObject> findMaxByUser(User _user, int _max) { 
if (_max <= 0) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("max <= 0: " + _max);
}
Long rowCount = (Long)createCriteria()
    .add(Restrictions.eq("m_queryUser", _user))
    .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
    .uniqueResult();

Collection<TestObject> results = createCriteria()
  .add(Restrictions.eq("m_queryUser", _user))
  .setFirstResult(1)
  .setMaxResults(_max)
  .list();
final int count = rowCount.intValue();
final int totalCount = count > results.size() 
    ? count : results.size();
return results;
```

This results in a `org.hibernate.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement` error.

The strange thing is, if I change DB implementations to Derby, the code works fine.  But there's something goofy happening using H2 when I try to use `.setMaxResults()`.  If I use `.setFetchSize()` instead it'll return all the results no problem, but going back to `.setMaxResults()` produced the above error.

Any help/information would be great.

Caused-by trace:

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT THIS_.ID AS ID1_0_5_, THIS_.CREATED_ON AS CREATED2_0_5_, THIS_.UPDATED_ON AS UPDATED3_0_5_, THIS_.VERSION AS VERSION4_0_5_, THIS_.FAVORITE_QUERY AS FAVORITE6_0_5_, THIS_.NAME AS NAME5_0_5_, THIS_.USER_KEY AS USER7_0_5_, USERQUERY2_.ID AS ID1_2_0_, USERQUERY2_.CREATED_ON AS CREATED2_2_0_, USERQUERY2_.UPDATED_ON AS UPDATED3_2_0_, USERQUERY2_.VERSION AS VERSION4_2_0_, USERQUERY2_.MAX_RESULTS AS MAX5_2_0_, USERQUERY2_.PROPERTIES AS PROPERTI6_2_0_, USERQUERY2_.QUERY_STRING AS QUERY7_2_0_, USERQUERY2_.USER_KEY AS USER9_2_0_, USERQUERY2_.TARGETS AS TARGETS8_2_0_, EXTUSER3_.EXT_USER AS EXT1_4_1_, EXTUSER3_.CREATED_ON AS CREATED2_4_1_, EXTUSER3_.UPDATED_ON AS UPDATED3_4_1_, EXTUSER3_.VERSION AS VERSION4_4_1_, M_SORTS4_.USER_QUERIES AS USER1_2_7_, QUERYSORT5_.ID AS SORTS2_3_7_, QUERYSORT5_.ID AS ID1_1_2_, QUERYSORT5_.CREATED_ON AS CREATED2_1_2_, QUERYSORT5_.UPDATED_ON AS UPDATED3_1_2_, QUERYSORT5_.VERSION AS VERSION4_1_2_, QUERYSORT5_.ELEMENT_NAME AS ELEMENT5_1_2_, QUERYSORT5_.SORT_ORDER AS SORT6_1_2_, QUERYSORT5_.TYPE AS TYPE7_1_2_, QUERYSORT5_.USER_QUERY AS USER8_1_2_, USERQUERY6_.ID AS ID1_2_3_, USERQUERY6_.CREATED_ON AS CREATED2_2_3_, USERQUERY6_.UPDATED_ON AS UPDATED3_2_3_, USERQUERY6_.VERSION AS VERSION4_2_3_, USERQUERY6_.MAX_RESULTS AS MAX5_2_3_, USERQUERY6_.PROPERTIES AS PROPERTI6_2_3_, USERQUERY6_.QUERY_STRING AS QUERY7_2_3_, USERQUERY6_.USER_KEY AS USER9_2_3_, USERQUERY6_.TARGETS AS TARGETS8_2_3_, EXTUSER7_.EXT_USER AS EXT1_4_4_, EXTUSER7_.CREATED_ON AS CREATED2_4_4_, EXTUSER7_.UPDATED_ON AS UPDATED3_4_4_, EXTUSER7_.VERSION AS VERSION4_4_4_ FROM IES_TEST_SCHEMA.LES_FAVORITES THIS_ LEFT OUTER JOIN IES_TEST_SCHEMA.LES_USER_QUERIES USERQUERY2_ ON THIS_.FAVORITE_QUERY=USERQUERY2_.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN IES_TEST_SCHEMA.LES_USERS EXTUSER3_ ON USERQUERY2_.USER_KEY=EXTUSER3_.EXT_USER LEFT OUTER JOIN IES_TEST_SCHEMA.LES_USER_QUERIES_SORTS M_SORTS4_ ON USERQUERY2_.ID=M_SORTS4_.USER_QUERIES LEFT OUTER JOIN IES_TEST_SCHEMA.LES_QUERY_SORTS QUERYSORT5_ ON M_SORTS4_.SORTS=QUERYSORT5_.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN IES_TEST_SCHEMA.LES_USER_QUERIES USERQUERY6_ ON QUERYSORT5_.USER_QUERY=USERQUERY6_.ID INNER JOIN IES_TEST_SCHEMA.LES_USERS EXTUSER7_ ON THIS_.USER_KEY=EXTUSER7_.EXT_USER WHERE THIS_.USER_KEY=? OFFSET[*] 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY "; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_0_5_, this_.created_on as created2_0_5_, this_.updated_on as updated3_0_5_, this_.version as version4_0_5_, this_.favorite_query as favorite6_0_5_, this_.name as name5_0_5_, this_.user_key as user7_0_5_, userquery2_.id as id1_2_0_, userquery2_.created_on as created2_2_0_, userquery2_.updated_on as updated3_2_0_, userquery2_.version as version4_2_0_, userquery2_.max_results as max5_2_0_, userquery2_.properties as properti6_2_0_, userquery2_.query_string as query7_2_0_, userquery2_.user_key as user9_2_0_, userquery2_.targets as targets8_2_0_, extuser3_.ext_user as ext1_4_1_, extuser3_.created_on as created2_4_1_, extuser3_.updated_on as updated3_4_1_, extuser3_.version as version4_4_1_, m_sorts4_.user_queries as user1_2_7_, querysort5_.id as sorts2_3_7_, querysort5_.id as id1_1_2_, querysort5_.created_on as created2_1_2_, querysort5_.updated_on as updated3_1_2_, querysort5_.version as version4_1_2_, querysort5_.element_name as element5_1_2_, querysort5_.sort_order as sort6_1_2_, querysort5_.type as type7_1_2_, querysort5_.user_query as user8_1_2_, userquery6_.id as id1_2_3_, userquery6_.created_on as created2_2_3_, userquery6_.updated_on as updated3_2_3_, userquery6_.version as version4_2_3_, userquery6_.max_results as max5_2_3_, userquery6_.properties as properti6_2_3_, userquery6_.query_string as query7_2_3_, userquery6_.user_key as user9_2_3_, userquery6_.targets as targets8_2_3_, extuser7_.ext_user as ext1_4_4_, extuser7_.created_on as created2_4_4_, extuser7_.updated_on as updated3_4_4_, extuser7_.version as version4_4_4_ from IES_TEST_SCHEMA.les_favorites this_ left outer join IES_TEST_SCHEMA.les_user_queries userquery2_ on this_.favorite_query=userquery2_.id left outer join IES_TEST_SCHEMA.les_users extuser3_ on userquery2_.user_key=extuser3_.ext_user left outer join IES_TEST_SCHEMA.les_user_queries_sorts m_sorts4_ on userquery2_.id=m_sorts4_.user_queries left outer join IES_TEST_SCHEMA.les_query_sorts querysort5_ on m_sorts4_.sorts=querysort5_.id left outer join IES_TEST_SCHEMA.les_user_queries userquery6_ on querysort5_.user_query=userquery6_.id inner join IES_TEST_SCHEMA.les_users extuser7_ on this_.user_key=extuser7_.ext_user where this_.user_key=? offset 1 rows fetch next 2 rows only [42000-171]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are not using the right dialect...

Double check what it is set to.

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: I had wondered about that. I"ll look into it and get back to you...thanks.

Comment: In a round about way, that was the problem. Thanks.