# Quarkus H2 gives me SQLGrammarException

Tags: h2, quarkus

I just updated my Quarkus to version 2.13. Final and now a test which uses H2 gives me a strange error:

Syntax error in SQL statement ......between ? and ? limit ? [42000-214]
2022-10-06 08:58:40,484 ERROR javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: **could not prepare statement**
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1626)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)

This my dependency:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

I thought this property could solve the problem in my case as well, but did not work:

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

reference: [Hibernate setMaxResults() with H2 SqlGrammarException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637108/hibernate-setmaxresults-with-h2-sqlgrammarexception)

Comment: Hi @Toni26, did find solution ? i'm in the same situation where the generated SQL contains "limit" keyword and throw the exception bellow.

Comment: hi. Yes. Hibernate does not support latest version of H2 . So just use version 1.4.XX  for now

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate solution the worked for me , is moving to the latest version of H2 this day and add to jdbc url the peroperty

```
;NON_KEYWORDS=limit
```